# Database Project - Set specific Settings ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT/sp_fulltext_database

Tags: sql, sql-server, dacpac

We are currently using a .sqlproject for an existing Database within Visual Studio.

When building the dacpac and running the command sqlpackage.exe /Action:script I am getting the following scripted changes:

```
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z :setvar DatabaseName "MyDb"
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z GO
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z USE [$(DatabaseName)];
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z GO
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z            FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z            WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z     BEGIN
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z         ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z             SET ANSI_NULLS ON,
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z                 ANSI_PADDING ON,
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z                 ANSI_WARNINGS ON,
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z                 ARITHABORT ON,
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z                 CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON,
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z                 QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON,
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z                 ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT ON,
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z                 CURSOR_DEFAULT LOCAL 
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z             WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z     END
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z 
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z 
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z GO
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z            FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z            WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z     BEGIN
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z         ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z             SET PAGE_VERIFY NONE 
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z             WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z     END
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z 
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z 
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z GO
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z IF fulltextserviceproperty(N'IsFulltextInstalled') = 1
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z     EXECUTE sp_fulltext_database 'enable';
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z 
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z 
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z GO
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z PRINT N'Update complete.';
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z 
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z 
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z GO
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z ##[warning] END SQL SCRIPT TO DEPLOY
2019-09-11T15:28:56.5658868Z ##[section]Finishing: Confirm SQL Deploy Script
```

I have managed to find the settings and change to match for the following:

- ANSI_NULLS
- ANSI_PADDING
- ANSI_WARNINGS
- ARITHABORT
- CONCAT_NULL_YEILDS_NULL
- QUOTED_IDENTIFIER
- CURSOR_DEFAULT
- SET_PAGE_VERIFY

But I can't for the life of me find where the last few properties are to change them to match the live db.

- ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT
- sp_fulltext_database

Any ideas on where I can find these last 2 so that all of our environments are matching the live database?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT setting as well, but I think "sp_fulltext_database" is enabled/disabled in the database project settings under

> Project Settings->Database Settings...
>
> Under the "Miscellaneous" tab
>
> "Enable full text search"

EDIT:
Apologies didn't see you were doing it under `sqlpackage`, not Visual Studio. But hopefully, that points you in the right direction.